# Flutter app ads and IAP on a streaming device (like Chromecast)

Tags: android, flutter, google-mobile-ads

I have a Flutter app that works on phones and Android TVs. I assumed this would also work on "streaming devices" like Chromecast with Google TV, but, after a user complaint, I've tested on Chromecast and ads do not load.

Does `google_mobile_ads` package work on streaming devices?